# Best practice on normalization

Tags: timescaledb

I'm wondering whether there is a best practice on the normalization of time series data.
I've a hyper table in a TimescaleDB looking like this

```
                      Table "public.mainsfrequency"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 time     | timestamp without time zone |           | not null |
 host     | text                        |           |          |
 location | text                        |           |          |
 freq     | double precision            |           |          |
```

Would it be a good idea to normalize `host` and `location` into separate (non-hyper) tables and use foreign keys within the above hyper table? I've read that referencing a hyper table using a foreign key is not supported, but what about the other direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct, it works to create foreign keys inside a hypertable to reference to a normal (non-hyper) table, but not opposite. So this will work:

```sql
CREATE TABLE host(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  host TEXT,
  location TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE mainsfrequency(
  time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  host_id INT REFERENCES hosts(host_id),
  freq DOUBLE PRECISION
);
SELECT create_hypertable('mainsfrequency','time');
```

When you decide, if it better to store `host` and `location` values inside the hypertable or move it into separate table, consider how much data will be stored, how unique the values, how data will be queried, and how hypertables will be used.

For example, repeating text of host names and locations for every row will occupy much more space than storing in a separate table if the text repeats a lot. However, if you will use [compression](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/compression), then you can save a lot of space while keeping the values inside hypertable.

If you will use [continuous aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/using-timescaledb/continuous-aggregates) to calculate and store aggregates, then you are limited to use only values stored in hypertables, since continuous aggregates do not support joins. For example, if you want to materialise aggregates for certain locations, then it cannot be done if the location is stored in a separate table.

So the following query cannot be put into a continuous aggregate:

```sql
SELECT time_bucket(INTERVAL '1h', time), host, AVG(freq)
FROM mainsfrequency, host
WHERE host_id = id AND location = 'NY'
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

To have such query in a continuous aggregate it will be:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mainsfrequency(
  time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  host TEXT,
  location TEXT,
  freq DOUBLE PRECISION
);
SELECT create_hypertable('mainsfrequency','time');

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mainsfrequency_hourly
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
SELECT time_bucket(INTERVAL '1h', time), host, AVG(freq)
FROM mainsfrequency
WHERE location = 'NY'
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: That is an elaborated answer! Excellent, very helpful, especially the hint about continuous aggregates.