# Timescaledb design timeseries with different frequency

Tags: database-design, timescaledb

I had started a TimescaleDB table design that has been working for some time now on a development environment. I am wondering now if this is the right design.

Basically, we have timeseries position measurements recorded every 15 seconds for a vehicle. We have a fleet of several vehicles. About 1/3 of measurements trigger a notification, and we record data about notification.

At the moment, because the frequency is different I separate the tracking measurements and the notification in 2 separates tables using the same time.

```
create table tracking(
  time timestamptz NOT NULL,
  vehicle_id int NOT NULL,
  latitude float NOT NULL,
  longitude float NOT NULL
)

create table notification(
  time timestamptz NOT NULL,
  vehicle_id int NOT NULL,
  content jsonb NOT NULL
)
```

I was thinking of merging those two tables back so we could get the notification content at the same time as the tracking data but I am surprised by the speed of the query:

```
SELECT t.*, n.content FROM tracking t LEFT JOIN notification n ON (n.time = t.time AND t.vehicle_id = n.vehicle_id)
```

So I am wondering if indeed my original design is the right one or if I should be merging those two tables and end up with:

```
create table tracking(
  time timestamptz NOT NULL,
  vehicle_id int NOT NULL,
  latitude float NOT NULL,
  longitude float NOT NULL,
  notification_content JSONB NULL
)
```

Bottom line, would you split time-series data into different tables if 1/3 of the time series data is associated with a lengthy json content.

Comment: Can you post EXPLAIN ANALYZE with BUFFER ON for your query? It can help a lot to understand the performance issue with the query.

Comment: @k_rus there is no performance issue. I thought there would be. I am wondering if the database design is correct, there seems to be no performance penalty in my original design, just wondering if it is usually  a correct way to do it.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I interpret your surprise into the wrong direction :) Still query plan can show few details, which might help in future, e.g., chunk exclusion. There is similar question about normalisation and an answer to it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67202335/840340
Having two tables might be an issue for continuous aggregates if you will use it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Denormalized single table has more advantages and likely to be more performant, than a schema with two tables and executing join queries.

To decide between two approaches, it is good to take into consideration the application complexity to insert data into the database and how data will be queried.

#### The query unrelated considerations

Few points, which are not related to the query performance, but good to consider:

1. Storing NULL values is cheap in PostgreSQL and TimescaleDB, thus having 2/3 of data with  no notification in the table is fine.
2. TimescaleDB doesn't allow reference constraints between hypertables, thus it is not possible to control integrity constraint on `vehicle_id` between the two table. While in the single table it is not an issue.
3. [Continuous aggregates](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/) do not support joins, thus if continuous aggregates will be considered in future, the single table is an advantage.

#### Query planning and potential performance

TimescaleDB implements important optimisation to execute queries over large volumes of data when the query is condition on time - [chunk exclusion](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/implementing-constraint-exclusion-for-faster-query-performance/), which excludes chunks, which don't satisfy the condition on time at query planning time. Below is investigating the chunk exclusion on the query example from the question.

To investigate the query plans I created a hypertable, indexes and inserted tiny amount of data:

```sql
SELECT create_hypertable('tracking','time');
SELECT create_hypertable('notification','time');

INSERT INTO tracking VALUES ('2020-02-03', 1, 1.0, 3.2),('2020-02-04', 1, 1.0, 3.2),('2020-02-03', 2, 1.0, 3.2),('2020-02-05', 2, 1.0, 3.2),('2020-02-06', 1, 1.0, 3.2);
INSERT INTO notification VALUES ('2020-02-03', 1, '{"note":"some"}'),('2020-02-05', 2, '{"note":"some"}');
INSERT INTO tracking VALUES ('2020-03-03', 1, 1.0, 3.2),('2020-03-04', 1, 1.0, 3.2),('2020-03-03', 2, 1.0, 3.2),('2020-03-05', 2, 1.0, 3.2),('2020-03-06', 1, 1.0, 3.2);
INSERT INTO notification VALUES ('2020-03-03', 1, '{"note":"some"}'),('2020-03-05', 2, '{"note":"some"}');

CREATE INDEX tracking_vt ON tracking (vehicle_id, time);
CREATE INDEX tracking_vt ON notification (vehicle_id, time);
```

Since the hypertables were created with default chunk size, i.e., 7 days, the data were inserted into following chunks:

```sql
SELECT hypertable_name, chunk_name, range_start, range_end FROM timescaledb_information.chunks;
 hypertable_name |    chunk_name     |      range_start       |       range_end
-----------------+-------------------+------------------------+------------------------
 tracking        | _hyper_3_8_chunk  | 2020-01-30 01:00:00+01 | 2020-02-06 01:00:00+01
 notification    | _hyper_4_9_chunk  | 2020-01-30 01:00:00+01 | 2020-02-06 01:00:00+01
 tracking        | _hyper_3_10_chunk | 2020-02-27 01:00:00+01 | 2020-03-05 01:00:00+01
 tracking        | _hyper_3_11_chunk | 2020-03-05 01:00:00+01 | 2020-03-12 01:00:00+01
 notification    | _hyper_4_12_chunk | 2020-02-27 01:00:00+01 | 2020-03-05 01:00:00+01
(5 rows)
```

Now let's get the explain plan for the query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT t.*, n.content FROM tracking t LEFT JOIN notification n ON (n.time = t.time AND t.vehicle_id = n.vehicle_id);
                                                            QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Left Join  (cost=2.12..5.35 rows=10 width=60) (actual time=0.051..0.069 rows=10 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: ((t.vehicle_id = n.vehicle_id) AND (t."time" = n."time"))
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..3.15 rows=10 width=28) (actual time=0.011..0.022 rows=10 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_8_chunk t  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=5 width=28) (actual time=0.010..0.011 rows=5 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_10_chunk t_1  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=28) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=4 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_11_chunk t_2  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=2.06..2.06 rows=4 width=44) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=4 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2.06 rows=4 width=44) (actual time=0.007..0.014 rows=4 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_4_9_chunk n  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=44) (actual time=0.006..0.007 rows=2 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_4_12_chunk n_1  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=44) (actual time=0.005..0.006 rows=2 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 1.881 ms
 Execution Time: 0.117 ms
(13 rows)
```

It is not common to query without condition on time, since the amount of data to retrieve will be enourmous on large data set. Thus I added a WHERE clause with a condition on time to retrieve only half of the data:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT t.*, n.content FROM tracking t LEFT JOIN notification n ON (n.time = t.time AND t.vehicle_id = n.vehicle_id) WHERE t.time > '2020-02-20';
                                                            QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Right Join  (cost=2.10..4.20 rows=2 width=60) (actual time=0.099..0.106 rows=5 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: ((n.vehicle_id = t.vehicle_id) AND (n."time" = t."time"))
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2.06 rows=4 width=44) (actual time=0.005..0.011 rows=4 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_4_9_chunk n  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=44) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=2 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_4_12_chunk n_1  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=44) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=2.07..2.07 rows=2 width=28) (actual time=0.044..0.044 rows=5 loops=1)
         Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2.07 rows=2 width=28) (actual time=0.011..0.019 rows=5 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_10_chunk t  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=4 loops=1)
                     Filter: ("time" > '2020-02-20 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone)
               ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_11_chunk t_1  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ("time" > '2020-02-20 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone)
 Planning Time: 4.546 ms
 Execution Time: 0.157 ms
(14 rows)
```

Note that the number of chunks read from `tracking` is 2 out of 3, and 2 out of 2 for `notification`. This means that [chunk exclusion](https://blog.timescale.com/blog/implementing-constraint-exclusion-for-faster-query-performance/) was done on `tracking`, but no chunks were excluded from `notification`. If TimescaleDB's query planner misses to exclude chunks, it can be a serious performance issue on large dataset.

I twicked the query to limit time against `notification` instead of `tracking` and the result is better:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT t.*, n.content FROM tracking t LEFT JOIN notification n ON (n.time = t.time AND t.vehicle_id = n.vehicle_id) WHERE n.time > '2020-02-20';
                                                         QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..3.13 rows=1 width=60) (actual time=0.019..0.037 rows=2 loops=1)
   Join Filter: ((t."time" = n."time") AND (t.vehicle_id = n.vehicle_id))
   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8
   ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_4_12_chunk n  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=2 loops=1)
         Filter: ("time" > '2020-02-20 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..2.07 rows=2 width=28) (actual time=0.003..0.007 rows=5 loops=2)
         ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_10_chunk t  (cost=0.00..1.05 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.003..0.004 rows=4 loops=2)
               Filter: ("time" > '2020-02-20 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone)
         ->  Seq Scan on _hyper_3_11_chunk t_1  (cost=0.00..1.01 rows=1 width=28) (actual time=0.002..0.003 rows=1 loops=2)
               Filter: ("time" > '2020-02-20 00:00:00+01'::timestamp with time zone)
 Planning Time: 1.161 ms
 Execution Time: 0.071 ms
(12 rows)
```

Chunks were excluded for both tables.

So it is possible to get efficient execution of join queries on normalized schema, however it can be tricky. Note that query plan might be different for different amount of data.

**Therefore**, if it doesn't add much complexity to the application to insert data into single denormalized table and queries retrieving both tracking and notification information (join queries) are expected, then the single table approach is, imho, preferable over the two tables approach with join queries.

Comment: You are making very good points. The storage of NULL values is interesting. The continuous aggregates non support for join is what decided it for me. I ended up refactoring it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sylvain thank you for your comment! I re-arranged my answer based on it, so it can be helpful to other developers.